# How to change the Currency Abbreviation (EUR, USD) to (Euros, US Dollars) in option for select [Ruby on Rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to change the (in Rails) option for select if the output is EUR, USD, ..... i want to Euros, US Dollar.

```
<%= select_tag('user[currency_id]', options_for_select(Currency.get_active.collect{|t| [t.name, t.id]}, @user.try(:currency_id) ), {:class => "bigselect"})  %>
```

Someone else has ideas?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should **translate** them with **I18n**:

```
Currency.get_active.map{ |t| [I18n.t("currencies.names.long.#{t.name}"), t.id] }
```

And in your *locale.yml* (example with *en.yml*):

```
# en.yml
currencies:
  names:
    long:
      usd: "US Dollars"
      eur: "Euros"
      #...
    short:
      usd: "$US"
      eur: "€"
```

OR an **alternative without a Translation system**:

```
class Currency < ActiveRecord::Base
  LONG_NAMES = { 
                 'EUR' => 'Euros', 
                 'USD' => 'US Dollars',
                 # ...
               }
  # ...  
end
```

And use it like this:

```
Currency.get_active.collect{ |t| [Currency.LONG_NAMES[t.name], t.id] }
```

In case the `t.name` returns an entry that is not in the `LONG_NAMES` constant, display the `t.name` attribute:

```
Currency.get_active.collect{ |t| [Currency.LONG_NAMES[t.name] || t.name, t.id] }
```

Comment: Thanks but my APP works on rails 1.6 version, you can tell me how to do by another method without I18n

Comment: I do not know what the problem is but the error, my APP crashes somewhere, problem here `LONG_NAMES = { 
                 'EUR': 'Euros', 
                 'USD': 'US Dollars',
                 # ...
               }
  # ...  `

Comment: The `# ...` are representating other entries, take them off the code

Comment: Of course I removed (# ...) but still not working


`class Currency <ActiveRecord :: Base

LONG_NAMES = {
                  'EUR': 'Euros',
                  'USD': 'US Dollars',
                }


   has_many: users

   validates_length_of: name, .................`

Comment: My bad, its the hash syntax, I updated my answer with `{ 'string' => 'otherstring' }` and not like `{ 'string': 'otherstirng' }`

Comment: does not work, I even try to views:

`<div class="fieldRow">
<label for="currency"> <% = _ ('Default_currency')%> </ label>
<%
LONG_NAMES = {
                 'EUR' => 'Euros',
                 'USD' => 'US Dollars',
    
               }
%>
<% = Select_tag ('user [currency_id]', options_for_select (Currency.get_active.collect {| t | [LONG_NAMES [t.name], t.id]}, @ user.try (: currency_id)), {: class => "bigselect"})%>
</ div>`

 does not work :-(((((

Comment: You have an extra coma `,` at the end of your Hash. There is also multiple syntax errors.

Comment: ActionView::TemplateError - compile error  dynamic constant assignment LONG_NAMES = { ^